# Density of states-phase uncertainty relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, bose-einstein-condensate

I came across this uncertainty relation for Density of states $N$ and phase $\theta$ in "Introduction to Many-Body Physics" by P Coleman on Page 15, equation (2.20).

$$\Delta N\Delta\theta >\approx 1\tag{2.20}$$

I am unable to understand this relation between $N$ and $\theta$ algebraically especially in how these two drive the emergent phenomena in Bose superfluid and laser. As in I want to understand this intuitively with this relation affects the formation of bose-condensation or cooper pairs. Also, why is it not greater than or approx equal to h bar (because that is what we get for the uncertainty in x and p; and for E-t)?

I have not taken Quantum field theory before. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: are you familiar with classical hamiltonian mechanics?

Comment: Yes, I have studied first three chapters from Landau and Lifshitz